# How do you undo on a US keyboard mac set to German keyboard, and where the ^ symbol from said keyboard as well?

Tags: keyboard

I have originally a US keyboard so the degrees/up arrow sign on the top left of an ORIGINAL GERMAN KEBOARD is actually the <> keys for me.

When I do Ctrl+Y it doesn't undo, nor does ctrl+z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs don't use Ctrl  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   as the main modifier, they use Cmd  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>

Undo *should* still be  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  on a German Keyboard, between T & U.
Not all apps use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>  for Undo, Many use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  instead. Adobe apps are switchable in prefs.

For any other app, you'd have to let us know which it is. Upload a photo of the actual keyboard & a snapshot of the layout from system prefs, eg

[image]